# Compute $E[X^2]$ for a random variable $X∼Unif(0,3)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, variance

So since $Var(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ and  that $E[X]^2=\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 $

and that $Var(X)=\left(\frac{b-a}{12}\right)^2 $ it implies that $Var(X)=\frac{3^2}{12}=\frac{3}{4} $

and that $E[X]^2=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2=\frac{9}{4} $

which implies that $E[X^2]=Var(X)+E[X]^2=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{9}{4}=\frac{12}{4}=3$

Is this correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I think there's a typo at the beginning of your second line - you need to divide by $12$, not by $2$. Either way, you fixed it in the following calculation

Comment: Yes you are right, that was my fault...Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's ok, though I'd just integrate $x^2$ against the PDF $1/3$ giving $$ E(X^2) = \int_0^3\frac{1}{3}x^2dx=3 $$

Comment: Yeah that's much more simple...But why did you put 1/3 in front? Is that the part of the definition(formula) or...?

Comment: Agree with other answerer that your way is best when you have variance and mean calculated for you and the integral isn't as easy.

Comment: It's the PDF for the uniform distribution on [0,3]. You need the $1/3$ as a normalization so that $\int p(x)dx = 1$

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to solve the problem. When you have a table of expected values and variances, this is a very slick way to calculate higher moments like $E(X^2)$.